# Add Text to a particular element in JSON array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, string, addition

I want add extra text to a particular element in array,
from below INPUT, I want to change "Image":"12001116"  to   "Image":"wp-content/upload/12001116.jpg".

So I want add "wp-content/upload/" $value['Image']; ".jpg"
Could someone please, Help!

**INPUT**

```
$json = '[
{
"Image":"12001116",
"Name":"Jean-Marc",
"CODE_POSTAL":"12630 ",
"VIL":"AGEN D AVEYRON",
"LATITUDE":"44.343518",
"LONGITUDE":"2.716004"
},
{
"Image":"1200558",
"Name":"Aurélien ",
"CODE_POSTAL":"12630 ",
"VIL":"AGEN D AVEYRON",
"LATITUDE":"42.343828",
"LONGITUDE":"2.920056"
}
]';
```

**and OUTPUT should be**

```
$json = '[
{
"Image":"wp-content/upload/12001116.jpg",
"Name":"Jean-Marc",
"CODE_POSTAL":"12630 ",
"VIL":"AGEN D AVEYRON",
"LATITUDE":"44.343518",
"LONGITUDE":"2.716004"
},
{
"Image":"wp-content/upload/1200558.jpg",
"Name":"Aurélien ",
"CODE_POSTAL":"12630 ",
"VIL":"AGEN D AVEYRON",
"LATITUDE":"42.343828",
"LONGITUDE":"2.920056"
}
]';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_map()` to loop over the objects:

```
$json = json_decode($input); // $input is the JSON input string
$newJson = array_map(function ($obj) {
      $obj->Image = 'wp-content/upload/' . $obj->Image . '.jpg';
      return $obj;
}, $json);
$output = json_encode($newJson, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo $output; // done!
```

EDIT:
If you don't want backslashes `\`, then change line 6 to:

```php
$output = json_encode($newJson, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Comment: Missing extensions when concatenating.  Please check your results.

Comment: @RanjitT I'm checking...

Comment: @RanjitT please give specifics rather than 'some error'.  The above code works for me (minus jpg extensions).  Is `$input` assigned/equal to your JSON string?

Comment: Hello, Thank you so much for your response. I've tried it, it seems to have some error.  Infact, its showing "wp-content\ /upload\ /12001116"   whic means its adding \/ instead of just / and also at the end, .jpg is missing.    Could you please make it work

Comment: Infact, its showing "wp-content\ /upload\ /12001116"   which means its adding \/ instead of just / and also at the end, .jpg is missing.    Could you please make it work

Comment: @RanjitT Yes, it'll convert every `/` to `\/` for some safety reasons. I've updated the answer. Now it'll append `.jpg` after the image path. I checked the above code and it works.

Comment: @ArRakin , thank you so much you are a life saver.     Its now showing     "wp-content\/upload\/12001116.jpg"    is it possible to make every \/ to just /  because this is to load the image the server... but with this "\/"  its not loading. Thanks again

Comment: @RanjitT Sure! Check out the updated answer and have a nice day!

Comment: @ArRakin My goodness! It worked like a charm. Thank you so much. you too have a great day!

Comment: @ArRakin   Sorry to interrupt you again. if possible. could you please have a look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70948560/trying-to-remove-nesting-from-json-array-in-php

Comment: @ArRakin Did you check this bro ?             https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70958044/remove-intial-nesting-in-json-array-with-php